# How are Mono<Void> and Mono.empty() different

Tags: java, spring, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, reactor

As per my understanding, in Spring WebFlux reactor

`Mono<Void>` refers for a void Mono

`Mono.empty()` refers to void, as calling anything over this gives a null pointer.

*How do these stand different in their usage ?*

Comment: `Mono<Void>` is a type. `Mono.empty()` is a method invocation that returns a Mono that [that completes without emitting any item](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#empty--).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`Mono<T>` is a generic type - in your specific situation it represents `Void` type as `Mono<Void>`

`Mono.empty()` - return a Mono that completes without emitting any item.

Let's assume that you got a method:

```
private Mono<Void> doNothing() {
    return Mono.empty();
}
```

When you want to chain anything after the method call that returns `Mono.empty()` it won't work with `flatMap` as it is `a completed Mono`.
In case you want continue another job after that method you can use operator `then`:

```
doNothing().then(doSomething())
```