# Spring Webflux ServerResponse is blank

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-webflux

I have been banging my head for this simple issue on this simple code :

```
@Bean
public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> refresh() {
    return route(GET("/api/refresh"), (request) ->
            request.principal().or(Mono.empty()).flatMap((it) -> {
                System.out.println(it);

                return ServerResponse.ok().body(Mono.just(new FreshStatus(true)), FreshStatus.class);
            }));
}

record FreshStatus(boolean isFresh) {}
```

I have two issues:

- When not authenticated, the code inside flatMap is not called, despite my .or clause
- When authenticated, the flatMap code is called, but the server response is just blank.

In both cases response is 200 OK.

I have tried using SecurityContextHolder nothing changed.

New code is:

```
            ServerResponse.ok().body(request.principal()
                    .map(it -> new FreshStatus(true))
                    .defaultIfEmpty(new FreshStatus(false)), FreshStatus.class));
```

Comment: Setting these two issues apart, for your second issue, are you able to simply return a server response without using any authentication?  Can you either set a breakpoint there or print out some log statements?

Comment: @vphilipnyc indeed `return route(GET("/api/refresh"), (request) -> ServerResponse.ok().body(Mono.just(new FreshStatus(true)), FreshStatus.class));`  works

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61822820/how-are-monovoid-and-mono-empty-different#:~:text=is%20a%20type.-,Mono.,completes%20without%20emitting%20any%20item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `principal()` method returns an empty `Mono`, the `flatMap()` method will not be called and the response will be empty.  `Mono.empty()` will return a Mono that completes without emitting any item.

You can try the `defaultIfEmpty()` method instead.

Not sure whether this is what you want, but something like:

```
return route(GET("/api/refresh"), (request) ->
            request.principal().defaultIfEmpty(new FreshStatus(false))
            .flatMap((it) -> {
                System.out.println(it);

                return ServerResponse.ok().body(Mono.just(it), FreshStatus.class);
            }));
```

As an aside, Josh Bloch would claim that in most cases, you're better off using an enum instead of a boolean.  I tend to agree.  This could be relevant for your `FreshStatus` record potentially.

Comment: Thanks, it works when unauthicated access now, but when accessing with an authenticated the request never finishes.

Comment: Can you check the output of the principal?  Like: `System.out.println("principal: "+request.principal());`. Just to see whether you have it configured correctly.

Comment: If there's an issue there, then I would check the gradle build file (or pom.xml) for any conflicts.  Start fresh from start.spring.io with a starter project if need be.

Comment: I think the issue is with the security config code. Since it's a whole other topic I'm gonna close thisk thanks for your time

Comment: Makes sense to look there esp if you get it working with an otherwise fresh project